# SqlServer Timeout in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, timeout

I have a SP which takes 20 seconds  in SqlServer environment  but sometimes in my ASP.NET page when I run the SP I get SqlServer timeout excaption.
I event set CommandTimeout and ConnectionTimeout to 60 but I still get the exception.
I would appreciate to help me.

Comment: one more thing I don't have any transaction.when I get this error I can run the SP in SqlServer management studio.

Comment: you said you sometime get this error, is this right?

Comment: yes sometimes..when I get this error I run 'Alter Proc ' command once and it works then again.

Answer (score 1):

Some other operation might be locking the table. set the timeout to a higher value and check.

while running the proc execute `sp_lock` and `sp_who2` system procedure for any locking

Comment: There is no lock on tables because when I get the exception I can run the SP in management studio but in my webpage I see timeout error and what's more after run alter SP my webpage works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
  cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

if you are executing a query taking long time.

Answer (score 0):

1) tried something like??

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyReport", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 3660; //// or set it zero (0)
```

2) and this???

3) Assuming your db server and point of execution are different, is your internet/intranet connectivity fine?
4) check for vpn connection (if used)

Comment: But the SP takes 20 seconds in the worst state and I'm wondering why it doesn't return data in my ASP.NET page and if simultaneously I run the SP in management studio it works very well.

Comment: checked internet/vpn conectivity??

Answer (score 0):

Execute the query from the SSMS and save the execution plan. Then run the application and have the SQL Profiler to capture the trace and then save the execution plan from profiler as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan).

Compare the two execution plan to find out the actual difference in execution.

Check for [parameter sniffing](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3257/different-approaches-to-correct-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/). If you still have the issue make sure the DB statistics are updated, sometimes this might be the issue after that drop and create the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the **sending parameters** from your application **to store procedure**.
try it again but this time use **SQL Server Profiler** to trace your query execution .
you can use **TextData column value** in SQL Server Profiler and run real executed query again to find the real problem.